# Hypothesis to split an even number as the sum of two primes as per Goldbach's Conjecture

Tags: number-theory, goldbachs-conjecture

I have the following conjecture in regard to Goldbach's Conjecture which I have found via my own experimentation. I wanted to run it by here to see if it is correct and can be proved formally.

---

$\forall$ N $\ge$ 20 s.t. N is **even** we define the set A(N) as

$$ A(N)=\{(a,b,c)\ |\ a<b<c<N\ s.t. (a,b,c)\ is\ a\ prime\ triplet\} $$

We also define the set B(N) as:

$$ B(N)=\{c\ |\ \forall(a,b,c)\in A(N)\}$$

Then $\exists\ c\in B(N)$ s.t.

$$ c\ and\ N-c\ are\ prime$$

---

Please do let me know what you think about this. I have programmatically verified it till $10^9$ and am working on testing it for larger numbers. However, I am unable to prove/disprove this mathematically.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture), Goldbach's Conjecture has already been verified for $n$ up to $4\times 10^{18}$.

Comment: @David I understand it has been verified up till that value, but there is no method to identify the primes except by trying via brute force. My goal of providing this is to reduce our search space to locate these primes

Comment: @Pathlessbark8 OK, but my point is, it looks like you still need a lot of brute force, and it's not clear that you have reduced the search space.  What reason do you have to believe that you have done so?

Comment: @StinkingBishop I didn't exactly understand your example. 3,5,11 isn't a prime triplet. I am not claiming no other method of splitting exists, I am just theorizing the method I suggested could reduce the primes we need to check

Comment: @David Clearly the number of prime triplets is lesser than the number of primes up to any number N. Moreover, for any tuple (a,b,c) we are only picking c and this drops the number of primes we need to check to a third of the total number of triplets.

Comment: I look forward to reading about it when you have pushed the bound past $4\times10^{18}$.

Comment: $$p+q=2n$$ has $$p\equiv q\equiv n\pmod 3$$  for all $$\{n\mid 3\nmid n\}$$

Comment: Okay most not all

Comment: Also, strong Goldbach, is weak Goldbach with one of the values in the sum set to 3.

Comment: Is the conjecture that all even numbers are the sum of two primes greater than 3 ? That's how this reads.

Comment: The Golbach's Conjecture is that every even number >= 2 can be written as the sum of two primes. In my attempt to prove this, I was trying to come up with a way to find these 2 prime numbers for any given even number. My conjecture states that for every even number N greater than 20, if we consider the set of largest primes from each prime triplet lesser than N, then there exists a prime p in that set such that N-p and p are both prime and hence a valid split for N to be written as the sum of two primes.

Comment: You can cut back on checks by noting that 2n=p+q where both 2p+1 and 2q+1 are primes causes a pair for 4n+2 another Goldbach equivalent is every natural number greater than 3 is equidistant two primes or is itself prime.  Like I pointed out mod 3 though, the distances either having 2n-3 prime or are divisible by 3. So it's only c congruent to n mod 3 that need inspection for the most part.